# Pass a <select> form option through the URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a select dropdown form, it has some values. The way my web app is set up is - when the dropdown select option changes, it triggers a JS function that populates data into a table.

What I want to do is, be able to pass the  option through the URL, so that when I visit the URL with maybe #selected_option added at the end of it, it will load up the page with that option selected.

I am open to any method that will easily accomplish this task for me. Right now, when I change select values, the URL doesnt change at all. Thanks!

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="refreshOrg()" id="selectTeam">
  <option value="dis" disabled selected>Please Select a Team..</option>
  <option value="1">Platform (ALL)</option>
  <option value="2">Operations Tools</option>
  <option value="3">Big Data Platform</option>
  <option value="4">Information Integration Governance</option>
  <option value="5">Cloud Data Services</option>
  <option value="6">Relational Analytics</option>
  <option value="7">SAP CoE</option>
  <option value="8">Business Analytics Platform</option>
  <option value="9">Competetive</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Check out [how to handle forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) - specifically with $_GET

Answer (score 1):

Pass the selected option as a query string and you can then check this against the value of each option as you are building it:

URL:

http://www.example.com/mypage?selectedOption=7

CODE:

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="refreshOrg()" id="selectTeam">
    <option value="dis" disabled>Please Select a Team..</option>
    <option value="1"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 1) { echo " selected"} ?>> Platform (ALL)</option>
    <option value="2"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 2) { echo " selected"} ?>> Operations Tools</option>
    <option value="3"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 3) { echo " selected"} ?>> Big Data Platform</option>
    <option value="4"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 4) { echo " selected"} ?>> Information Integration Governance</option>
    <option value="5"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 5) { echo " selected"} ?>> Cloud Data Services</option>
    <option value="6"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 6) { echo " selected"} ?>> Relational Analytics</option>
    <option value="7"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 7) { echo " selected"} ?>> SAP CoE </option>
    <option value="8"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 8) { echo " selected"} ?>> Business Analytics Platform </option>
    <option value="9"<?php if ($_GET['selectedOption'] == 9) { echo " selected"} ?>> Competetive </option>
</select>
```

As @jqheart says, creating the URL in refreshOrg() is pretty simple:

```
window.location='your_URL?selectedOption='+$('#selectTeam').attr('option :selected');
```

Comment: Im not sure how this works, can you explain exactly how to add location.href?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited that part, so that line should make the browser load the generated URL which will include the selected option as part of the query string

Answer (score 0):

In `refreshOrg()` function, hope you are using a URL in this function and you are using jquery in your page.

Inside `refreshOrg()`,

```
location.href='your_URL?selectTeamVal='+$('#selectTeam').attr('option :selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it client-side!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var urlMatch = document.location.search.match(/selectedOption=([^&]+)/);
    if (urlMatch != null)
    {
        $('#selectTeam').val(urlMatch[1]);
    }
});
```